# My bios does not appear to recognize the UBS with a Ubuntu install imparted on it

Tags: system-installation

I set up a flash drive with Ubuntu using rufus , I have disabled windows but locker and I have disabled safe boot , however it appears that my bios does not recognize the flash drive plugged in as a viable boot device . Most advice I have seen on this topic is for individuals who have already installed their other is but I can't even get my bios to recognize the installer . Initially I thought the issue was with the dongle I'm using as my laptop has no traditional USB ports , but I found a video where someone uses a very similar dongle .

Comment: What do you mean by 'not appear to recognize ,,,' ? Can you select the USB in boot-order in bios setup ?

Comment: Start by checking your media - does it work in a different computer?

Comment: Some UEFI settings (BIOS) boot order have two layers of boot ordering.  First the usual device boot order (USB should be before the HDD), and maybe a second UEFI order (like you might see from a UEFI boot menu function key). Can you successfully boot the USB from the UEFI boot menu (some function key at power up)?

Comment: You've provided few specifics, so we can't really provide much. Your details read like a user-procedure error as most likely, and you've not provided sufficient details to rule out any procedural error you've made. You haven't mentioned what Ubuntu product, what release or ISO of that product, if its the correct architecture for your *unstated* hardware, nor if you *cloned* the ISO to media or reformatted it (*and if reformatted via options in `rufus` if you used appropriate options for your unstated* ISO*). What Ubuntu product, what release, which ISO? what architecture? what machine?  etc

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why Doesn't a Bootable USB Boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1190764/why-doesnt-a-bootable-usb-boot)